# Serialize object map with gson - object is incomplete

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I want to serialize an object Bar, which contains primitive types and a HashMap.

```
public class Bar{
 int simpleValue;
 HashMap<Foo,Integer> map;
...
}

public class Foo{
 ...
}
```

I use Gson to create a Json-String:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(barObject);
```

This results in the following string:

```
{"simpleValue":9,"map":{"com.blabla.Foo@2d9b7da":120,...}}
```

Why is there just a string representation of the object-name?

What am i doing wrong?

`gson.toJson(fooObject)` prints the correct properties of Foo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is printing out the string representation of the object name because the `Bar` class has a `Map` object with the key as a class whose `toString()` has not been overridden. 
`gson` uses `toString()` implementation to generate the json key.
Since you have not implemented it, It is falling back to the default `Object.toString()` for key generation. Hence the output.
Below is the source to demonstrate the behaviour,

```
public class Bar {
    Map<Foo, Integer> map;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        TracingAspect t = new Bar();
        t.map = new HashMap<>();
        t.map.put(new Foo("ff"), 5);
        String j = g.toJson(t);
        System.out.println(j);
    }

}
class Foo {
    String a;
    public Foo (String a) {this.a=a;}
    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return a;
    }
}
```

The output of following is,

```
{"map":{"ff":5}}
```

Comment: Thanks! In addition: I just found the setting "enableComplexMapKeySerialization()" within gson, which does exactly what i want.